# System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object - Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, .net, missingmethodexception

I went back to the old project - Windows Forms app in .NET Framework which compiled version works fine. I've been trying to run this project but I got error:

`System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. Obviously all needed services are registered and all of them have apropiate constructor (all with parameters) and as I mentioned before - this project had worked without any problem few months ago.

Unfortunately I can't insert the original code but these are normal type classes like:

```
public class SomethingService : ISomethingService
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly ILogger<ISomethingService> logger;

    public SomethingService(IRepository repository, 
        ILogger<ISomethingService> logger)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Registered like:
`services.AddTransient<ISomethingService, SomethingService>();`

I've reinstalled all nuggets, been trying to re-define constructors, change the order of certain dependencies execution and move the project to other environments - always the same story.

Comment: Are all of those dependencies being added? 
`services.AddTransient<ILogger<T>>();`
`services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();`

It seems like debugging the full code would likely show the actual problem. Like a missing dependency or more likely trying to manually instantiate this class using something like `new SomethingService();` which would fail and produce this error. Also this class is named `ISomethingService` and does not inherit from any interface which is likely a problem.

Comment: It was just example - in real code everything seems to be okay - every service has been registered in DI. Error occures in the first deependency that program trying to solve and event if I change order of execution always first service throws this exception - doesnt matter which one it is and which dependencies it has. Also as I said - it worked few months ago without this problem

Comment: Pl check your constructor for SomethingService(it should be public SomethingService(IRepository.., ILogger<SomethingService>...))

Comment: Is it being "new"d somewhere without parameters?  Create a parameterless constructor and see where its used.  Also your parameters need to be compatible with Transient life cycles....Are they?

Comment: That `MissingMethodException` isn't coming from DI. The stack trace should reveal where the problem is, or at least which part of which framework is complaining.